# TypeError: this.httpService.post is not a function in nestJs unit testing

Tags: unit-testing, nestjs

am writing unit test cases of auth.service.ts file which return promise

```
import { HttpService } from '@nestjs/axios';
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigService } from '../config/config.service';
import { AppBuilderToolLogger } from '../config/logger.module';
import { ApiConstants } from '../constants/api-constants';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  constructor(
    private readonly logger: AppBuilderToolLogger,
    private readonly httpService: HttpService,
    private readonly configService: ConfigService,
  ) {}

  /**
   * getUspBasedOnSessionID fucntion call api and return a response
   *
   * @param cookie
   * @returns
   */
  async getUspBasedOnSessionID(cookie: string): Promise<any> {
    const data = await new Promise((resolve) => {
      this.httpService
        .post<any>(
          this.configService.get('COMMON_API_URL') +
            ApiConstants.userGetUspBasedOnSessionID,
          '',
          {
            headers: {
              Cookie: cookie,
            },
          },
        )
        .subscribe({
          next: (response) => {
            resolve(response.data);
          },
          error: (error) => {
            this.logger.error('Calling error getUspBasedOnSessionID()', error);
            resolve('An error happened on getUspBasedOnSessionID!');
          },
        });
    });
    return data;
  }
}
```

this is my spec.ts where am writing all tests
i want to call spyon and check test of error msg and reponse

```
import { Test, TestingModule } from '@nestjs/testing';
import { describe, expect } from '@jest/globals';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { AppBuilderToolLogger, ConfigModule, ConfigService } from '../config';
import { HttpModule } from '@nestjs/axios';
import { HttpService } from '@nestjs/axios';


describe('AuthService', () => {
  let service: AuthService;
  let httpService: HttpService;
  beforeEach(async () => {
    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      imports: [HttpModule],

      providers: [
        AuthService,
        {
            provide: HttpService,
            useValue: {}
        },
        AppBuilderToolLogger,
        {
          provide: ConfigService,
          useValue: new ConfigService(`.env.dev`),
        },
      ],
    }).compile();

    service = module.get<AuthService>(AuthService);
    httpService = module.get<HttpService>(HttpService);
  });

  it('should be defined', () => {
    expect(service).toBeDefined();
  });

  describe('getUspBasedOnSessionID function', () => {


    it('post request successfully ', async () => {
    
        const mockData = {"name": 'test'};
        const mockResponse = <any> {data: mockData,};
        
        // jest.spyOn(httpService, 'post').mockImplementationOnce(() => mockResponse);

        service.getUspBasedOnSessionID('random-cookie').then((data) => {
            expect(data).toEqual(mockData);
        }
        );
    });

  });
});
```

it works fine without using spyon

```
 it('should be defined', () => {
    expect(service).toBeDefined();
  });

  describe('getUspBasedOnSessionID function', () => {

    it('getUspBasedOnSessionID should not return null', async () => {
      const cookie = 'random-cookie';

      const result = await service.getUspBasedOnSessionID(cookie);
      expect(result).not.toBeNull();
      expect(result).toBe('An error happened on getUspBasedOnSessionID!');
    });
  });
```

but i expect to use spyon to write unit test cases
the above error occurs when i used
// jest.spyOn(httpService, 'post').mockImplementationOnce(() => mockResponse);
am using promise inside the function and promise uses httpservice post method and it calls subscribe method and inside it it called the error handler

Answer (score 0):

current httpService object is empty object

write a below code in providers array

```js
{
   provide: HttpService,
   useValue: {
      post: jest.fn(() => of({ data: { name: 'test'} }))
   }
}
```